# Select content between the nth and the nth+N marker

Tags: javascript, regex

For example, how can I select the segment of this phrase:

```
49up_88x126x476mm_3mm gutters_28375x40_Ft First_Rollem_sw
```

between the 2nd and 3rd "_" or between the 2nd and 4th, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Not that easy but, this is one way.

Basic regex `^(?:[^_]*_){A}([^_]*(?:_[^_]*){B})_`

***Where***
A < B
A = *From Number*
B = *To Number* - *From Number* - 1

Capture group 1 contains the *between* contents.

For example, 2 to 4 would be
A = `2`
B = 4 - 2 - 1 = `1`

The regex is `^(?:[^_]*_){2}([^_]*(?:_[^_]*){1})_`

***Output***

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 : len 39 ) 
49up_88x126x476mm_3mm gutters_28375x40_  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 18 : len 20 ) 
3mm gutters_28375x40
```

---

Readable regex

```
 ^ 
 (?:
      [^_]* 
      _                # From = 2
 ){2}

 (                     # (1 start)
      [^_]*                    
      (?:
           _    
           [^_]*                    
      ){1}
 )                     # (1 end)
 _                     # To = 4
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without regex.

Just split on the underscore.
Then take the elements you need from the resulting array.
And join the elements you want back together.

**Javascript example:**

```js
var str = '49up_88x126x476mm_3mm gutters_28375x40_Ft First_Rollem_sw';
console.log(str);

var arr = str.split('_');

 
var str_2_3 = arr.slice(2-1,3).join('_'); //2-1, because index starts at 0
console.log(str_2_3);

var str_2_4 = arr.slice(2-1,4).join('_');  
console.log(str_2_4);
```